# which is the right one / preferable sentence? Physics. An air bubble is released from a given depth under the surface of sea

Tags: sentence-choice

If you can please explain it in a few words which is right / wrong or in which book can I see to this topic

- **Calculate from how deep the bubble arrived.**
- **Calculate how deep from the bubble arrived.**
- **Calculate how deep the bubble arrived from.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these is well-phrased. I would write this as

> Calculate the depth from which the bubble arrived.

or even better

> Calculate the depth at which the bubble was released.

"Calculate from how deep" and "Calculate  how deep from" are both ungrammatical formations.

Comment: Can I use here "from how deep" somehow? It makes sense, for me at least...

Comment: @gladiator I don't see any way that "from how deep" can be used in a variant of the example sentence and be grammatically correct, or sound correct to a native spe4aker. It will probably be understood, but perceived as poor English.